# recover a number from call history

Tags: call-history

I called a number about a month ago but never saved it, now when I tried to look it up I couldn't find it

My phone is showing the calls of the past 2 weeks only

Is there anyway to recover that number on my 5.1 android phone ( I never deleted the number from the call history ) preferably without having to root the phone

Comment: Look at the cell bill call log info and see if it is listed there?  Not sure if all carriers list all outgoing/incoming calls, maybe this is an option for you.

Comment: unfortunatly it's not an option

Answer (score 0):

i think your problem could be solved very easily if your phone is rooted. Try GT Call Recovery app

if your phone isn't, try this apps (try some luck, it worked on my HTC phone but kept crashing on my Sony Phone but i think still worth a try)

**call history manager**

or

**Call history**

play store: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jp.main.itinfo.tan.callhistory&hl=en
apk file if you can't access Play Store: http://choilieng.com/apk-on-pc/jp.main.itinfo.tan.callhistory.apk

hope it help.